# How to change UI colors for gitk?

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitk

I use *gitk* for keeping an eye onto branches, commits and so on ...
I am running Ubuntu 14.04. and noticed that the background color of the branch label is different in comparison to what I am used to on another machine running Ubuntu 13.10. Currently I have Git 1.9.3 installed.

[image: Branch in gitk]

Is there a way to customize the background color of the branch label in *gitk*?

Comment: Though I know this is long solved the replacement color is `lime`. I ran into this same problem just recently when I updated my gitk in Windows.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That appears to be the `headbgcolor`, which is not available from the GUI colour settings.

Close `gitk`, then modify `~/.config/git/gitk` (or `~/.gitk`, check whether either of these files exists already) and change

```
set headbgcolor green
```

to some other colour. Hex codes appear to be supported unquoted, e.g.

```
set headbgcolor #123456
```

Comment: +1 You can check how it's done in the official Dracula theme for gitk: https://github.com/dracula/gitk (*Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer.*)

Answer (score 4):

For Windows, you need to change `headbgcolor` in your `%HOMEPATH%\.gitk`hidden file.